# Orchard . DynamicForms module is enabled but code not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.9

I'm using Orchard 1.9.2 version, I deployed the complied code for orchard on Azure web app, created a new default tenant, and when I enabled the DynamicForms module, it got enabled but its migration did not run, admin menu item for 'Form Submissions' did not appear, seems like all the code for the module is not running. Please help me out if you have any suggestions.
I need a solution for 1.9.2

Comment: What does the logs say?

Comment: No error is logged at all

Comment: What is displayed in the modules page for the DynamicForms module? Is there any notification?

Comment: Can you check App_Data/Dependencies and see if it contains the Orchard.DynamicForms.dll file? If not, try and copy it from Modules/Orchard.DynamicForms into that folder and try again.

Comment: It appears this question is also asked by the same person here: https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/6260#issuecomment-319523301 Crossposting is cool, but make sure to provide links to them as well. Otherwise someone might be wasting time finding an answer which you may have already gotten elsewhere.

Comment: The issue has also appeared for me in the compiled 1.10.2 zip file.